# Change of variables in probability homework problem

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, spheres, density-function

I have the following problem I'm having trouble starting with:

> Consider a probability function $p(\textbf{x})$ in $d$ dimensions
>   which is a function only of radius $r=\|\textbf{x}\|$ and which has a
>    Gaussian form
>
> $$p(\textbf{x}) =
>  \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\|\textbf{x}\|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right).$$
>
> By changing variables from Cartesian to polar coordinates, show that
>   the probability mass inside a thin shell of radius $r$ and thickness
>   $\epsilon$ is given by $\rho(r)\epsilon$ where
>
> $$\rho(r) =
>  \frac{S_dr^{d-1}}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$
>
> where $S_d$ is the surface area of a unit sphere in $d$ dimensions.
>   That is:
>
> $$S_d=\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)},$$
>
> where $$\Gamma(x)\equiv\int_0^\infty u^{x-1}e^{-u}\;du$$

So my problem here is that I'm not quite getting the picture where I'm supposed to start. What I understand from the problem statement is that I need to first, do the change the variables in function $p(\textbf{x})$, and then integrate this function over an interval of thickness $\epsilon$ to get the probability mass?

How should I start? I could try doing this problem myself after I get the picture what I'm supposed to do. The problem statement is not 100% unambiguous for me.

P.S. This problem is from the book: Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition, Christopher M. Bishop, page 29, problem 1.4.

**UPDATE:**

in the problem statement in Bishop's book the normalizing constant is NOT $1/(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}$, but $1/(2\pi\sigma^2)^{1/2}$. I think this is a typo mistake, because otherwise the integral wouldn't sum into $1$. What do you think? I corrected $1/(2\pi\sigma^2)^{1/2}\; \rightarrow \; 1/(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}$ in my original question

Thank you!

Comment: This may be useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183423/drawing-samples-from-a-multivariate-normal-distribution-subject-to-quadratic-con

Comment: Thank you for the help @Sobi =)

Comment: You're basically asked to compute $\int_r^{r+\epsilon}p(\boldsymbol x) d\boldsymbol x$ by changing variables to polar $(\rho,\theta)\in\mathbb R^+\times \mathbb S^{d-1}$ (the latter being the sphere of radius $1$ in $d$-dimenstional space, $\|\boldsymbol x\|=\rho$. Since $p$ does not depend on $\theta$, work out first the integral with respect to $\theta$.

Comment: a physicist might say that you have to average over the angular degrees of freedom, so you calculate the prop. distribiution of a vector to have a specific length but regardless what his exact position is.

Comment: Thank you for your comments all =)

Comment: Why -1 for this question? I can correct any mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

My idea is that, if I can show that ([n-sphere wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_volume_element)):

$$\int_{\theta_{d-1}=0}^{2\pi}\int_{\theta_{d-2}=0}^\pi\cdots\int_{\theta_1=0}^\pi\int_{r=0}^\infty p(r)\,r^{d-1}\sin^{d-2}(\theta_{1}) \sin^{d-3}(\theta_{2}) \cdots \sin(\theta_{d-2})\,dr\,d\theta_1\,d\theta_2\,\cdots d\theta_{d-1}$$

$$=\int_\Omega d\Omega_{d-1} \int_0^\infty p(r)\,r^{d-1}\,dr=1,$$

where $\int_\Omega d\Omega_{d-1}$ is the angular components of the integral and is equal to the surface area of $d$-dimensional unit sphere $S_d$, that is:

$$S_d=\int_\Omega d\Omega_{d-1}=\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(d/2)},$$

where $\Gamma(d/2)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). If I can show that the above integral is equal to $1$, then

$$\int_\Omega d\Omega_{d-1} \int_0^\infty p(r)\,r^{d-1}\,dr=S_d\int_0^\infty p(r)\,r^{d-1}\,dr = \int_0^\infty \rho(r)\,dr=1,$$

which would mean that $\rho(r)\epsilon$ is the probability mass (probability mass = probability density $\times$ volume ) of shell of radius $r$ and thickness $\epsilon=dr$, which is what I'm supposed to show. So I do the integral:

$$\int_\Omega d\Omega_{d-1} \int_0^\infty p(r)\,r^{d-1}\,dr=S_d \int_0^\infty p(r)\,r^{d-1}\,dr=S_d\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}}\exp\left({-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\,r^{d-1}\,dr$$

$$=\frac{S_d}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}}\int_0^\infty\exp\left({-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}}\right)\,r^{d-1}\,dr=\frac{S_d}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}}\cdot\frac{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}}{S_d}=1.$$

The last integral is solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568309/how-to-calculate-the-integral-int-0-infty-exp-left-fracx22-sigma2-ri). Because of the final result, I conclude that the problem is done. $\blacksquare $

Comment: Please let me know if made a mistake or the solution is not sufficient.

Comment: I also picked the same approach as you with the hyperspherical coordinates and the Surface area equality.