# How to calculate the integral $\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)x^{d-1}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)x^{d-1}\,dx,$$

where $\sigma$ and $d$ are constants. How to solve this? Am I supposed to use the gamma function here? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why don't you try the change of variables $u = \frac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}$?

Comment: I will give it a go =) Thank you

Comment: u could also integrate by parts and try to employ the functional equation of the gamma function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got it myself already =) Thank you @Pragabhava for your suggestion. At first tried substitution in order to get to identity form:

$$\Gamma(d) = \int_0^\infty r^{d-1}e^{-r}\,dr$$

In this approach I failed, but then I found out the following identity involving change of variables from cartesian to polar coordinates:

> $$\int_0^\infty
>  e^{-r^2}r^{d-1}\,dr=\frac{\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^d\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x_i^2}\,dx_i}{S_d},\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(*)$$

where $S_d$ is the surface area of an $d$-dimensional unit sphere. With this identity it seemed to work. So my problem was:

$$\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)x^{d-1}\,dx,$$

So I used substitution: $\displaystyle u=bx,$ where $b=(\sqrt{2\sigma^2})^{-1}$. Now I get:

$$\frac{du}{dx}=b, \;\;dx =\frac{1}{b}\,du.$$

Knowing $(*)$ I used this substitution:

$$\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)x^{d-1}\,dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\left(\frac{u}{b}\right)^{d-1}b^{-1}\,du  $$

$$=\frac{1}{b^{d}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}u^{d-1}\,du.$$

Seeing that the limits of integration stay the same, I now use $(*)$ and the other identity:

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$

So I get:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}u^{d-1}\,du= \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{S_d}$$

so:

$$\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)x^{d-1}\,dx= \frac{\pi^{d/2}}{S_db^d}=\frac{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{d/2}}{S_d}$$

Comment: Please let me know if I made a mistake somewhere :)

Comment: Pragabhava's substitution should work very well, and doesn't require $d$ to be an integer.  I don't know why you failed in that.

Comment: Hi @RobertIsrael aah yes. I noticed now, I made a mistake in my first attempt. Got it now also with that substitution. Thank you! + 1